# How to traversal Generic object properties in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, backend

The problem is that I often encounter a scene that needs to traverse the instance object's property as another object method incoming parameters when the method calls. Like follows:

```
//Step 1
var criteria =new Criteria();
SqlCommand cmd =SqlCommandManager.GetDataCommand("SearchOrderList");
//Step 2
//The define of the SetParameterValue method is :
//public void SetParameterValue(string paramName, object val);
cmd.SetParameterValue("@SellerID",criteria.SellerID );
cmd.SetParameterValue("@DateFrom", criteria.SentDateFrom);
cmd.SetParameterValue("@DateTo", criteria.SentDateTo);
cmd.SetParameterValue("@StartRowIndex", criteria.PagingInfo.StartRowIndex);
cmd.SetParameterValue("@PageSize", criteria.PagingInfo.PageSize);
cmd.SetParameterValue("@SortField", criteria.PagingInfo.SortField);
cmd.SetParameterValue("@SortType", criteria.PagingInfo.SortType);
//cmd.SetPa........
//Step 3
cmd.ExecuteEntityList<Model>();
```

How I make a flexible and scalable method to simplify step 2.
I have a thought is that make a Generic Method to deal this:

```
public static void SetParameterValues<T>(this DataCommand cmd,T _object)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(cmd,null))
            throw new ArgumentException("The Parameter cmd must be not null", "cmd");
        if (!object.ReferenceEquals(_object, null))
        {
            //to do ...
        }

    }
```

but I'm confused what I should Proceed to deal with next step(I have made an extension Method).
So could you guys help me check out this problem?

Comment: If you are trying to do this in order to execute commands in a SQL database, then this is basically a solved problem - read up on ORMs like Entity Framework or nHibernate.

Comment: Generics is not really going to help you here at all. The way to do this, if you are really bent on generalizing (why is anyone’s guess), would be via Reflection but you’d need some custom attribute support to know what properties you really need to add (if all public properties are subject to be parameters then you wouldn’t need it). In any case, your `T` is about as “useless” as `object` so choose the latter and don’t make your method seem to be doing something it isn’t.

Comment: That is what I'm going to do, but I don't know how to build it. After I finish traversal the property I may use such as Attribute(or something else) to infer what property needs traversing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making one method generic and then have do somehow differentiate between the different types, create overloaded versions of the method

```
public static void SetParameterValue(this DataCommand cmd, string parameter, int value)
public static void SetParameterValue(this DataCommand cmd, string parameter, string value)
public static void SetParameterValue(this DataCommand cmd, string parameter, DateTime value)
...
```

E.g.

```
public static void SetParameterValue(this DataCommand cmd, string parameter, int value)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(cmd,null))
        throw new ArgumentException("The Parameter cmd must be not null", "cmd");
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter, SqlDbType.Int).Value = value;
}
```

But if you want to infer the prameter name, you would have to use another approach. To be able to access the property name, you need an expression tree:

```
public static void SetParameterValue<T>(this DataCommand cmd, Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var member = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("We need a member expression of type obj.PropertyName");

    var prop = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (prop == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("We need a property, not a field");

    string name = prop.Name;
    T value = expr.Compile()();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + name, value);
}
```

You must then call it using a lambda expression

```
cmd.SetParameterValue(() => criteria.SellerID);
```

Comment: ...Or use one of the many ORM frameworks, which do this for you